# What exactly is setmetatable, and how do I avoid it for security reasons?

Tags: lua, lua-table, metatable, nlua

Generally sandboxes block setmetatable like shown here:

```
local function memoize(f)

  local mt = {}
  local t = setmetatable({}, mt)

  function mt:__index(k)
    local v = f(k)
    t[k] = v
    return v
  end

  return t
end
```

The question is, I want to not use setmetatable. What is it exactly and how would I get around it? Is it simply a global variable that is a copied 'mt' variable in the above case? Is there something specific I should be doing?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. You can disable `setmetatable` easily enough, just like with any Lua sandbox. Are you asking how to allow someone to still get the effects of `setmetatable` without calling it, or by calling a more "secure" version of it? What security issues are you trying to avoid, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sandboxes written by competent developers don't block the regular `setmetatable` function. For example, Wikipedia uses [the Scribunto extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto), which allows anyone to write and run Lua on the site, and it allows unrestricted use of `setmetatable`. (It does, however, block `debug.setmetatable`, along with most of the rest of `debug`.) In general, when a sandbox does block `setmetatable`, it's because its developers either don't understand how userdata works, don't understand that `debug.setmetatable` and `setmetatable` are different, and/or don't understand what `__metatable` does. There's no need for you to restrict it.